# XML file update using python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am new to python and XML. I need to delete UserName and all his corresponding FeatureIds from the XML file. I tried using xml.etree.ElementTree but not able to delete FeatureIds. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BusinessRule>
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CovRDMMetaData>
        <Config>
            <Type>Business Rule</Type>
            <Category>Device</Category>
        </Config>
        <Properties>
            <PropertyInfo>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>FeatureEntitlementDetails</Name>
                    <Path>Rules\FeatureEntitlementDetails.xml</Path>
                    <Version>4.0.12</Version>
                </Rule>
                <Target>
                    <ClientName>Money Exchange Client</ClientName>
                    <ClientVersion>7.8.7</ClientVersion>
                    <DeviceType>Money AP15</DeviceType>
                </Target>
            </PropertyInfo>
        </Properties>
    </CovRDMMetaData>
    <CovRDMData>
        <SetFeatureRetirement>
             <IsRetired>No</IsRetired>
             <MessageIfRetired>Please upgrade ROLEX client to use Set Feature option</MessageIfRetired>
       </SetFeatureRetirement>
       <EnabledFeatureListForUsers>
           <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>raj@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>0</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>1</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>2</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>3</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>4</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>5</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>6</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
            <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>mana@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>0</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>1</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>2</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>3</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>4</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>5</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>6</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>7</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>8</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>9</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>10</FeatureId>           
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
            <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>thomas@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>0</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>1</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>2</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>3</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>4</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>5</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>6</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>7</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>8</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>9</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>10</FeatureId>           
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
                          <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>anyka@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>7</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
       </EnabledFeatureListForUsers>
    </CovRDMData>
</BusinessRule>
```

For example I want to delete UserName raj and all his FeatureIds from 0 to 6. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I tried using xml.etree.ElementTree but not able to delete FeatureIds." - Please show us your code.

Comment: By deleting the UserName you mean to delete the entire ```<FeatureEntitlementDetail>``` of that ```<UserName>``` ?

Comment: @Ram Yes I want to delete the entire `<FeatureEntitlementDetail>` of that `<UserName>`

Comment: @mzjn I am new to xml. My code is not matured one. Thats why I did not post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using `beautifulsoup`. [Docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

- First select the `<UserName>` with text (as Raj in this case.).
- Find it's parent i.e the `<FeatureEntitlementDetail>` using the `.findParent()` method.
- Now deleting the `<FeatureEntitlementDetail>` will delete the entire tree of Username Raj. You can do that using [`.decompose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Here is the full code.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """<YOUR XML GOES HERE>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'xml')
u = soup.find('UserName', text='raj@abc.com')
fed = u.findParent()

fed.decompose()
print(soup.prettify())
```

**You can see that there is no `<UserName>` Raj and it's related `<FeatureIds>` by printing the `soup`.**

Comment: Pls let me know how to install requests, bs4 and beautiful soup

Comment: You can do that using ```pip```. See this - https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/

Comment: Yes I installed them It worked. Thank you

Comment: If I want to add new user name john@abc.com and featureIds for ex say 3, 5, 6. How to do that?